# How Can I Generate Dynamic Buttons in Winforms based on the data table values from Database in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

Actually I am pretty new to C#. I have two tables in database named as "Categories" and "MenuItems" respectively. What I want is when the form loads, I should get all Categories rows from the database and display them as text on dynamically generated buttons (number of buttons depends on the number of category rows), I have already accomplished it using following code:

```
   private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=Shezi;Initial Catalog=RMS;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        con.Open();
        string commandText = "select Categories From Categories";
        cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, con);
        SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(sdr);
        con.Close();
        int btnName = 0;
        if (dt.Rows.Count>0)
        {
            btnName++;

            int PosY = 5;
            int rowCount = -1;
            int numOfRows = dt.Rows.Count;
            for(int i=0; i<numOfRows; i++)
            {
                rowCount++;
                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    variables.btnText = dt.Rows[rowCount].Field<string>(0); 
                }
                Button button = new Button();
                button.Enabled = true;
                button.Text = variables.btnText;
                button.BackColor = Color.Green;
                button.ForeColor = Color.White;
                button.Width = 150;
                button.Height = 50;
                button.Name = "button" + btnName;
                button.Location = new Point(-2, PosY);
                button.Font = new Font("Georgia", 12);
                button.Click += Button_Click;
                panel.Controls.Add(button);
                PosY += 55;
            }
        }



    }
```

My Above code does generate dynamic buttons based on the category rows from database and here is my main problem, what I want is when a user clicks any of the dynamically generated buttons, the text of that button should be searched in menu items (obviously text of the button will be a category text), application should search that text in MenuItems rows and filter out all MenuItems that are saved against that category (For example if dynamically generated button had text "Burger", program should fetch all menu items from burger category and display then on more newly generated dynamic buttons) and similarly if button with category Cheese is clicked, it should fetch and create new dynamic buttons and populate Cheese menu items. 
This is what I have tried to get new dynamic buttons based on the buttons click so far:

```
 private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        dt = manager.GetMenuItems(menuItems);
        var count = dt.Rows.Count;
        //int btnName = 0;

        int PosX = 160;
        int rowCount = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            //btnName++;
            rowCount++;
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                menuItems.MenuText = dt.Rows[rowCount].Field<string>(0);
                //categories.btnText = row.Field<string>("Categories", DataRowVersion.Original);//do not undo
                DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
                dv.RowFilter = "MenuItem = MenuItem";
                DataTable dt1 = dv.ToTable();
                menuItems.MenuText = dt1.ToString();
            }
            //string btnText = count.ToString();
            Button btn1 = new Button();
            btn1.Enabled = true;
            btn1.Text = menuItems.MenuText;

            btn1.BackColor = Color.Navy;
            btn1.ForeColor = Color.White;
            btn1.Width = 150;
            btn1.Height = 50;
            btn1.Name = "btn1";


            btn1.Location = new Point(PosX, 10);
            btn1.Font = new Font("Georgia", 12);
            btn1.Click += new EventHandler(btn1_Click);
            pnlCategories.Controls.Add(btn1);
            PosX += 150;

            //var newvalue =  ds.Tables[0].Rows[1].ItemArray[0].ToString();    

        }


    }
```

I have searched many ways but couldn't find anything similar, I have tried different threads on stackoverflow too but no luck, need help!

Comment: What columns do you have inside MenuItems Table?

Comment: Use following : string[] columnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(x => x.ColumnName).ToArray();

Answer (score 0):

Try following code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication62
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        static DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        const int NUMBER_OF_BUTTON_COLUMNS = 6;
        const int BUTTON_HEIGHT = 50;
        const int BUTTON_WIDTH = 50;
        const int BUTTON_MARGIN = 50;


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add("Col_" + i.ToString(), typeof(string));
            }
            AddButtons();
        }

        public void AddButtons()
        {
            String[] columnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(x => x.ColumnName).ToArray();
            for(int i = 0; i < columnNames.Length; i++)
            {

                Button button = new Button();
                button.Text = columnNames[i];
                int column = i % NUMBER_OF_BUTTON_COLUMNS;
                int row = i / NUMBER_OF_BUTTON_COLUMNS;
                button.Left = column * (BUTTON_MARGIN + BUTTON_WIDTH);
                button.Top = row * (BUTTON_MARGIN + BUTTON_HEIGHT);
                button.Width = BUTTON_WIDTH;
                button.Height = BUTTON_HEIGHT;
                this.Controls.Add(button);
                button.Click +=new EventHandler(Button_Click);
            }

        }
        public void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button button = sender as Button;
            string buttonName = button.Text;
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this what you need

```
void GenerateButton(FlowLayoutPanel pnl)
        {
            Button CategoryButton = new Button
            {
                Enabled = true,
                Text = ItemName,
                BackColor = Color.Green,
                ForeColor = Color.White,
                Width = 150,
                Height = 50,
                Name = ItemName,
                Font = new Font("Georgia", 12)
            };

            void SearchItemsInThisCategory(object sender , EventArgs e)
            {
                foreach(Button button in pnl.Controls.OfType<Button>())  //Remove others categories buttons
                {
                    if (button.Name != CategoryButton.Name)
                    {
                        pnl.Controls.Remove(button);
                    }
                }
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Shezi;Initial Catalog=RMS;Integrated Security=True"))
                {
                    SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter($"select {CategoryButton.Text} From MenuItems", con);
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    dataAdapter.Fill(dt);


                    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        ItemName = row[CategoryButton.Text].ToString(); 
                        GenerateButton(pnl);
                    }

                }

            }
            CategoryButton.Click += SearchItemsInThisCategory;
            pnl.Controls.Add(CategoryButton);
        }

        public void GetAllCategories(FlowLayoutPanel pnl)
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Shezi;Initial Catalog=RMS;Integrated Security=True"))
            {
                SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select Categories From Categories", con);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dataAdapter.Fill(dt);


                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    ItemName = row["Categories"].ToString(); //Assume Categories columns contains all categories
                    GenerateButton(pnl);
                }

            }

        }
```

Test

```
public string ItemName { get; set; }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GetAllCategories(flowLayoutPanel1);
        }
```

**Explanation**

I suggest you to use FlowLayoutPanel instead of Panel

I have declared property called ItemName which will recieve every CategoryName in Form1_Load and CategoryButton Name and Text will be equal to ItemName

I added onClick Event to the generated Buttons
 - First Delete others buttons except itself
 - Then it will use it's text to select only 'ColumnName' in MenutItem Table then it retrieve all rows data and assign each row cell value into GeneratedButton again

Comment: Yes, sounds like a great suggest

Answer (score 0):

**Hi, never mind experts I solved this problem by getting the dynamic button text and then searching it in the database to get menuitems stored against it, here is code: **

```
using BusinessManager;
using DataAccess;
using Domain;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace RestuarnetManagementSystem.Softangles
{
    public partial class POS : Form
    {
        Manager manager = new Manager();
        DataClass dataClass = new DataClass();
        Categories categories = new Categories();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ButtonData bd = new ButtonData();
        MenuItems menuItems = new MenuItems();
        int btnName = 0;
        public POS()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void tabPage1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void panel7_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            //ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString()

            //dt = manager.DeployButtonCategoryText(categories);
            dt = manager.DeployButtonCategoryText(categories);
            var count = dt.Rows.Count;
            //int btnName = 0;

            int PosY = 5;
            int rowCount = -1;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                //btnName++;
                rowCount++;
                btnName++;
                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    categories.btnText = dt.Rows[rowCount].Field<string>(0);
                    //categories.btnText = row.Field<string>("Categories", DataRowVersion.Original);
                }
                //string btnText = count.ToString();
                Button btn1 = new Button();
                btn1.Enabled = true;
                btn1.Text = categories.btnText;
                categories.btnText = btn1.Text;
                btn1.BackColor = Color.Navy;
                btn1.ForeColor = Color.White;
                btn1.Width = 150;
                btn1.Height = 50;
                btn1.Name = "btn1"+btnName;


                btn1.Location = new Point(-2, PosY);
                btn1.Font = new Font("Georgia", 12);
                btn1.Click += new EventHandler(btn1_Click);
                pnlCategories.Controls.Add(btn1);
                PosY += 55;

                //var newvalue =  ds.Tables[0].Rows[1].ItemArray[0].ToString();
            }




        }

        private void POS_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {





        }

        private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pnlMenuItems.Controls.Clear();
            Button btn = sender as Button;
             menuItems.FindMenuItems = btn.Text;
              dt =  manager.GetMenuItems(menuItems);
             int rowCount = dt.Rows.Count;
            int counter = -1;
            if(dt.Rows.Count>0)
            {

                int PosX = 100;
                for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
                {
                    btnName++;
                    counter++;
                    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        menuItems.MenuText = dt.Rows[counter].Field<string>(0);
                    }

                    Button button = new Button();
                    button.Enabled = true;
                    button.Text = menuItems.MenuText;
                    button.BackColor = Color.Navy;
                    button.ForeColor = Color.White;
                    button.Font = new Font("Georgia", 12);
                    button.Location = new Point(PosX, 10);
                    button.Width = 150;
                    button.Height = 50;
                    button.Name = "button" + btnName;
                    button.Click += new EventHandler(button_Click);
                    pnlMenuItems.Controls.Add(button);
                    PosX += 150;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Failed!");
            }
            //dt = manager.GetMenuItems(menuItems);
            //int count = dt.Rows.Count;
            ////int btnName = 0;

            //int PosX = 160;
            //int rowCount = -1;
            //for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            //{
            //    //btnName++;
            //    rowCount++;
            //    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            //    {
            //       menuItems.MenuText = dt.Rows[rowCount].Field<string>(0);

            //    }
            //    //string btnText = count.ToString();
            //    Button btn2 = new Button();
            //    btn2.Enabled = true;
            //    btn2.Text = menuItems.MenuText;

            //    btn2.BackColor = Color.Navy;
            //    btn2.ForeColor = Color.White;
            //    btn2.Width = 150;
            //    btn2.Height = 50;
            //    btn2.Name = "btn2";


            //    btn2.Location = new Point(PosX, 10);
            //    btn2.Font = new Font("Georgia", 12);
            //    btn2.Click += new EventHandler(btn2_Click);
            //    pnlCategories.Controls.Add(btn2);
            //    PosX += 150;

            //    //var newvalue =  ds.Tables[0].Rows[1].ItemArray[0].ToString();    

        }

        private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Test");
        }


    }


}
```